# Increase the ImageView or ImageButton Size using XML

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been trying to increase the size of a ImageButton/ImageView in a relative layout with all the possible attributes but had no success. no matter what size I put. As I checked the displayed button is 32dp, if I lower the value the image will resize to small but will never enlarge more than 32dp.

I am kinda confused here, 32px is xhdpi image size, is that the reason its not enlarging ?

Image is the made accordingly to support all the 5 dpi (mdpi, hdpi, etc ..)

this activity belong to layout-large as I am trying to make it for large screen as well.

here is how I am doing it:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/quantity_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_qty"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_button_add"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to increase the size then do this:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_plus"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_qty"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_button_add"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Instead of Wrap_Content for width & height specify some size

change the width & height according to your required need

**Edit:**

wrap_content will always just wrap your image & will not increase the size of the imageview

To use on different size devices:

put the values in res->values->dimens folder for normal, small & large devices

and use like :

```
android:layout_width="@dimens/widthSize"

android:layout_width="@dimens/heightSize"
```

Comment: it did the job but the buttons are now blurred as they were stretched. Isn't there anyway to make use of buttons i've placed in every drawable folder ?

Comment: change scaleType & the images you put in different drawables will work automatically android is smart enough to identify the device

Comment: @VipiNNegi Didn't this solve your this very question ?

Comment: yeah information about the dimens is quite helpful but Is there any other way to fetch image from hdpi drawable instead of mdpi ?. So that I can have the crisp image.

Comment: the process you are talking about is automatically managed by the Android OS as it is smart enough to decide what is suitable for which device

Comment: well for my case, same drawable image is being taken for large and normal layout.

Comment: it depends on the pixels & quality or density of the device resolution

Comment: Well ultimately layout_width and height helped me .. although I've had to create new bigger image and place directly in drawable and had to compress with layout width and height .. thanks .. !!

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using wrap content for your width and height. With those set it will always just wrap the image and not be any large.... Even if your MaxWidth is set to a larger size. You will need to set those values to a specific value either in your XML or in your class in Java. Hope this helps!

Comment: you're partially right. I have another layout where the layout width and height are set to wrap content and changes in maxHeight is actually making a difference. I don't understand as it works for that situation but not on this :(

This is the working one : 
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/spicy"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/type"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_spicy"
android:maxHeight="22dp" />

its quite complex layout actually :D

Comment: Is that also for an ImageView though? Since Image view contains a canvas and will used for loading in resource like bitmap or image or whatever it does NOT work exactly like LinearLayout, TextView , EditText , etc. You will need to set a height and width other than WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT to get the desired effect consistently.

Comment: Yeah I get the same response on both ImageView and ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can change height and width accordingly using layout_width,layout_height tag.scaleType="fitXY" can be distorting the image so use scaleType="fitCenter" maybe that can help.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/quantity_plus"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_qty"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:src="@drawable/ic_button_add"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:maxWidth="100dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: it will always distort the image, as it is more than 32dp (the source of image from hdpi drawable folder). fitCenter didn't help either :(

Comment: ok.Maybe you can try making the image in .9.png to fix the scaling.

Comment: .9.png has different effect as far as I understand. It can't be use to enlarge circle type buttons ..  but quite effective in stretching rounded corner rectangular buttons etc ..  
so no, it didn't help me :( thanks for the help tho :(